# Pure local development environment throwing CORS error

Tags: cors, local

I am trying to develop my website locally using Node, Express, and MySQL.  In doing this I have installed a local MySQL server.  When I run my local node svrApp.js web server and then connect to localhost:3000 (using Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)), I get a CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) error.

I have done a ton of research on CORS and I get what it is, why it is, etc.  But what I still don't understand is why I am needing to use it when everything I'm doing is local.  That should all be the same domain, right?  Same localhost, same port.  My identical version of the code in production (out in the world) works fine without any CORS handling whatsoever.  So, What's going on locally such that I'm getting told I am using a cross domain?  I'm not convinced I need to be doing this, but I cannot seem to find what the problem is that's triggering this CORS error.

If I have to use CORS here, then fine, but if that's the case, then for all my research I'm still missing something fundamental because I'm not able to get it working even with the things I've found.

The code below is the client side code making the SQL request to the server to render a table with the results of a server side generated select query.  Again, everything is locally hosted.  The pages, the SQL server, all of it.

```
var ip = "localhost:3000/";

function afterPageLoad(){
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = {};
req.open("GET", ip+"EAselect", true);
req.withCredentials = true;
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.addEventListener("load", function(dataResponse, status){
    if(req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){
        dataResponse =  JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        buildTable(dataResponse);
    }else{
        console.log("Error: " + req.status + ", " + req.statusText);
    }
});
req.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Below is the route handler on the server.  I added the response headers that are supposed to allow CORS access, but no joy.

```
/* Select Query*/
app.get("/EAselect", function(req,res,next){
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept");
pool.query("SELECT * FROM workouts", function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err){
        console.log("query failure. " + err.description);
        next(err);
        return;
    }else{

        res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
    }
});
});
```

I would expect to simply be able to connect to my local resources without CORS implementation on either server or client since everything is local.

The result I'm getting is:

```
Failed to load localhost:3000/EAselect: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I have searched here extensively for something related to CORS and locally hosted services, but found nothing that specifically addresses this issue.

That's everything I can think of to add for relevant information.  If I've miss something that's needed to assist, let me know and I'll happily edit.  I appreciate any assistance or explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to specify the protocol:

```
var ip = "http://localhost:3000/";
```

Comment: My apologies for getting back to this so late.  I had a work week happen.  Thank you for the extra set of eyes on this, hannes!  That fix changed the error which allowed me to get it going!  Thank you!